# Missing last IP address

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a file and I'm trying to store ip addresses into an array.  My plan is store data up to comma or store characters after the addresses into dummy variable. My code works up to the 2nd line for some reason. Any help would be great.

Blacklist.csv:

```
46.30.45.65, good.recycle2learn.com
22.51.66.23, hothouse.com
83.98.11.48, monkeyhouse.com
```

The code:

```
void Blacklist()
{
  FILE *blist;
  char quotations = 0;

  blist = fopen("blacklist.csv", "r");
  if (blist == NULL)
  {
    //Quit if something goes wrong
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
  {
    fscanf(blist, "%d.%d.%d.%d,", &blacklist[i][0], &blacklist[i][1],
        &blacklist[i][2], &blacklist[i][3]);
    while (quotations != '\n')
    {
      fscanf(blist, "%c,", &quotations);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
  {
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", blacklist[i][0], blacklist[i][1], blacklist[i][2],
        blacklist[i][3]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @cpp_prog: Changing indention is one thing, changing code is another. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: First, this is a very poor way of reading from a file.  :(  Check out [getline()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).  You should never hardcode the number of lines `for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)`, define a MAX to match your data storage limits.  Also, you have not shown were `blacklist` is defined, so we don't know if you have sufficient storage to capture the data they way you are trying to.  You could be scribbling...

Answer (score 4):

After reading each line, you are not resetting your `quotations` variable (which is not named very well, given what it is being used for). Once you reach the first line break, your `while` loop will never be entered again.  Had you run your code in a debugger, you would have seen that happening.

Either reset the variable after reading an ip address:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // <-- use < instead of <=
{
    fscanf(blist, "%d.%d.%d.%d,", &blacklist[i][0], &blacklist[i][1], &blacklist[i][2], &blacklist[i][3]);
    quotations = 0; // <-- add this
    while (quotations != '\n')
    {
        fscanf(blist, "%c", &quotations); // <-- no comma after %c
    }
}
```

Or else use a `do..while` loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    fscanf(blist, "%d.%d.%d.%d,", &blacklist[i][0], &blacklist[i][1], &blacklist[i][2], &blacklist[i][3]);
    do
    {
        fscanf(blist, "%c", &quotations);
    }
    while (quotations != '\n');
}
```

**Update**: that being said, your code is not handling the possibility of the csv file containing blank lines in between each IP entry (as shown in your question) or a line break missing after the last entry.  To account for those, try using `fgets()` or `getline()` to read the file line-by-line into a local buffer, using `sscanf()` to parse the buffer as needed.

```
int blacklist[3][4];
int numblacklist;

void Blacklist()
{
  FILE *blist;
  char line[64];

  memset(blacklist, 0, sizeof(blacklist));
  numblacklist = 0;

  blist = fopen("blacklist.csv", "r");
  if (blist == NULL)
  {
    //Quit if something goes wrong
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (fgets(line, 64, blist))
  {
    if (sscanf(line, "%d.%d.%d.%d,", &blacklist[numblacklist][0], &blacklist[numblacklist][1], &blacklist[numblacklist][2], &blacklist[numblacklist][3]) == 4)
    {
      numblacklist++;
      if (numblacklist == 3)
        break;
    }
  }

  fclose(blist);

  for (int i = 0; i < numblacklist; i++)
  {
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", blacklist[i][0], blacklist[i][1], blacklist[i][2], blacklist[i][3]);
  }
}
```

Or:

```
int blacklist[3][4];
int numblacklist;

void Blacklist()
{
  FILE *blist;
  size_t linelen;
  char *line;

  memset(blacklist, 0, sizeof(blacklist));
  numblacklist = 0;

  blist = fopen("blacklist.csv", "r");
  if (blist == NULL)
  {
    //Quit if something goes wrong
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  line = NULL;
  linelen = 0;

  while (getline(&line, &linelen, blist) != -1)
  {
    if (sscanf(line, "%d.%d.%d.%d,", &blacklist[numblacklist][0], &blacklist[numblacklist][1], &blacklist[numblacklist][2], &blacklist[numblacklist][3]) == 4)
    {
      numblacklist++;
      if (numblacklist == 3)
        break;
    }
  }

  free(line);
  fclose(blist);

  for (int i = 0; i < numblacklist; i++)
  {
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", blacklist[i][0], blacklist[i][1], blacklist[i][2], blacklist[i][3]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I cant see my output. I believe I am stuck in the while loop.

Comment: Does your csv file actually contain blank lines in between each IP entry, as shown in your question? If so, your code does not account for that. Is there a line break after the last entry? If not, the `while` loop gets stuck in an endless loop since you are not doing error handling on `fscanf()` to detect EOF. Try using `fgets()` or similar function to read the file line-by-line into a buffer, then use `sscanf()` to parse each non-empty buffer as needed.

Comment: Nope, they are all underneath each other. I just presented it this way for clarification

Comment: Please always present data EXACTLY as it really is to void confusion.